Setting a custom highlight for a certain filetype
I'm trying to set up a minimal Vim configuration, and want to highlight all instances of the words FOO and BAR inside all *cpp files.
My .vimrc:
syntax enable
source config/highlights.vim

Inside config/highlights.vim:
augroup myHighlighting
  autocmd FileType cpp highlight FooWord ctermbg=216
  autocmd FileType cpp match FooWord /\<FOO\>/
  autocmd FileType cpp highlight BarWord ctermbg=219
  autocmd FileType cpp match BarWord /\<BAR\>/
augroup END

It looks like only the last group is highlighted -- only instances of BAR. Now if I put the two FooWord lines underneath the BarWord, then only FOO is highlighted.
Alternatively, if I create another augroup, the same thing happens:
augroup myHighlighting
  autocmd FileType cpp highlight FooWord ctermbg=216
  autocmd FileType cpp match FooWord /\<FOO\>/
augroup END
augroup myOtherHighlighting
  autocmd FileType cpp highlight BarWord ctermbg=219
  autocmd FileType cpp match BarWord /\<BAR\>/
augroup END

Still, only BAR is highlighted in this case. How do I fix this?

:help :match can only be used once. See :help matchadd() for a better method.

Or use :match Foo and :2match Bar. Or switch to :h :syn-keyword.

If this is considered a (part of/extension of) a cpp syntax then use :syntax match instead of :match

Or better, extend cpp syntax with ~/.vim/after/syntax/cpp.vim
syntax match FooWord /\<FOO\>/
syntax match BarWord /\<BAR\>/
syntax match BazWord /\<BAZ\>/

highlight FooWord guibg=red
highlight BarWord guibg=blue
highlight BazWord guibg=green

and it would just work for cpp filetype.
If it is not an extension of a syntax (shouldn't be affected by existing syntax rules as in highlight foo/bar/baz even in comments or strings), use matchadd() function or :match/:2match/:3match commands.
matchadd() if you have more than 3 things to highlight.


Thanks, I just added these snippets to my config and it worked nicely.
The augroup with matchadd was giving my an error that matchadd was not an editor command. So I changed it to an augroup with only the highlight commands, plus autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.cpp call mySetupFunction(). And in mySetupFunction() I call matchadd(...) as you did in your example and it worked. Not sure why this is the case, though.

oh, that is because I use vim9script where you can omit :call in function calls.
